# Does Flaming Sphere do fire damage and/or radiant damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, damage

Looking at the Flaming Sphere spell (p. 242 PHB), the spell description uses the phrase “sheds bright light in a 20ft radius”.  Can it be inferred that this does radiant damage?

Comment: Sorry, it's a bit confusing what you are saying, light doesn't directly relate to radiant damage, radiant damage is generally a divine light. But, then your title sounds like you mean to ask if fire and radiant are the same, but that isn't what is in your question. This is just all very confusing, and I can't even start to figure out what you are actually asking. This is in dire need of editing on your end, because I can't figure out what this means and presumably other people can't either

Comment: Also, if you are strictly asking what it's RAW damage type is, it's literally in the spell description, so are you trying to ask something else, because I can not figure this question out.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### No

The spell specifies the damage in the last sentence of the first paragraph.

> The creature takes 2d6 fire damage on a failed save, or half as much damage on a successful one.

So moving the sphere into a creature and forcing a saving throw against the damage is only causing fire damage

> If you ram the sphere into a creature, that creature
>   must make the saving throw against the sphere’s
>   damage, and the sphere stops moving this turn.

It only explicitly states that it gives off light or ignites (starts on fire) objects;

> The sphere ignites flammable objects not being worn or carried, and it sheds bright light in a 20-foot radius and dim light for an additional 20 feet.

If it was going to do radiant damage, it would explicitly state so.